# Нужно ли закрывать соединение с бд

Tags: mysqli, php

Нужно ли закрывать соединение с базой данных в целях безопасности? в конце скрипта к примеру регистрации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще простого - когда php-скрипт видит закрывающий тег ?> интерпретатор завершает свою работу. Все переменные умирают, объекты классов исчезают, все открытые дескрипторы файлов закрываются, ссылки на базы данных перестают существовать. Не переживайте.

Answer (score 5):

- когда скрипт заканчивает свою работу, соединение закрывается автоматически
- во время работы скрипта помешать ему удалённо выполниться возможности тоже нет

мой ответ -> *НЕТ*

P.S> Опасайтесь за:

- SQL инъекцию
- Фильтруйте все входящие данные
- Файл конфигов к базе (был недоступен из вне)
- Вызов модулей приложения "прямой ссылкой"
- Папку "аплоад", куда грузятся внешние файлы

Answer (score 3):

В целях безопасности не имеет смысла, пока ваш скрипт не передает подключение наружу в чистом виде (не уверен, что это возможно на PHP).
В целях чистоты кода - да, особенно на PHP, когда не знаешь, как именно он упадет. Пока незакрытых подключений не встречал, но, думаю, есть вероятность падения без завершающей обработки.